# Pre-Deploy Script on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a rails application to AWS. One of the gem's had a dependency and needs certain files installed on the server before `bundle install` is run during deployment. In my `.ebextensions` file I have the following

```
01-oracle_sdk:
    sources:
      /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
  02-oracle-basic:
    sources:
      /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
  03-oracle_sql_plus:
    sources:
      /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
  04-container_commands:
    00_oracle_dir:
      command: "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/instantclient_12_1"
```

From what I can tell, none of this is getting run pre-deploy. It fails when it tries to install the gem because that directory is not there. When I SSH into the instance, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set and none of the zipfiles were downloaded and unzipped by the `source` command.

1) Is my syntax in correct 2) How do I get these commands to execute PRE deploy/bundle install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EB has a specific folder where you can execute scripts to run *pre-deploy*. I created a `.config` file in my `.ebextensions` with bash commands I wanted executed pre deploy. It creates a file in `"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/` that gets run

**001_script.config**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/001_oracle.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      bash commands you want executed here
      ...
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, **.ebextensions** is a directory, not a file. Within that directory, you need to create a file with a `.config` extension.

Also, YAML is very whitespace sensitive, so you need to be consistent with your spacing.

Try this instead (I'm not 100% sure that `sources` can take multiple files, however - you might need to make three separate .config files...)

**.ebextensions/01-oracle.config**

```
sources:
  /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
  /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
  /usr/lib: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
```

Finally, setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in this way won't work; it'll be set for the duration of the deployment, but will not persist. You can set environment variables from the command line using `eb setenv`, or from the Configuration tab on the ElasticBeanstalk console.

More information can be found [in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).